# Jquery fadeIn loop stop, but finish fading in before stop not working

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have looped fadeIn/fadeOut.
On hover I want to get fadein->stop effect, and than restart the animation on mouse out.
Can't figure it out :(

html:

```
<style>
div{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background-color:black;  
}​
</style>

<div>
</div>
```

Here is js code:

```
function fade(){
$('div').fadeIn(2000, function(){
   $('div').fadeOut(2000, fade());                           
    })
}

fade();

$('div').hover(function(){
    $('div').fadeIn({duration:100, queue:false}).stop(true, true);
},function(){
    fade();
});​
```

Here is a JsFiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/5Zqcu/55/

Thank you for your help

Comment: Still not clear on what you want to do here.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaidul/5Zqcu/64/)

```
function fade(){
    $('div').fadeIn(2000, function(){
       $('div').fadeOut(2000, fade);                           
    })
}

fade();

$('div').hover(function(){
    $('div').stop(true);
},function(){
    fade();
});​
```

Comment: `stop` doesn't accept a callback, in your fiddle it works (stopping the animation from doing unexpected things) because it is evaluating the callback as a true value and clearing the event queue. You can simply change this to `stop(true)` also the additional enclosure for the hover out isn't required.

Comment: Also another note is that the fade function is being called after fadeIn is complete, not after fadeOut is complete, so it is queuing more animations. Change `.fadeOut(2000, fade())` to `.fadeOut(2000, fade)` to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

u need to stop before do the animate/fadeIn:

```
function fade(){
    $('div').fadeIn(2000, function(){ 
       $('div').fadeOut(2000, fade);                           
    })
}
fade();

$('div').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1},100);
},function(){
    fade(); 
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want some sort of pulsing element, where it fades in and out until you mouseover it, where it should then become fully opaque. You are better off using `fadeTo` as `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` often take the starting opacity as the shown opacity.

Also, you don't need to use the callback to line up the next animation you can just string them together because they automatically get queued to the `fx` queue. When you want to stop the animation you will need to use `stop(true)`, if you use `stop()` it will stop the current animation but start the next one.

```
function fade() {
    $("div").fadeTo(2000, 0).fadeTo(2000, 1, fade);
}

fade(); // Start throbbing

$("div").hover(function() {
    // You want to clear the queue but not call the complete callback
    // and then rapidly fade in
    $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(100, 1);
}, fade);
```

Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5Zqcu/66/

Answer (score 0):

The same thing in ultra-short:

```
$('div').on('mouseenter').stop(true).fadeTo(100,1)
   ._.on('mouseleave').repeat().fadeTo(2000,0).fadeTo(2000,1,$)
   ._.mouseleave();
```

This example, http://jsfiddle.net/creativecouple/rLcqD/, uses a little [plugin jquery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/) for the short syntax.